# prove/disprove: does this sequence converges?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

I need your help to decide whether the following statement is true/false:

if $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}(a_{n+1} - a_n) = 0 $ then the sequence  $(a_n)_{n=1}^\infty $ converges.

I think that the only sequence that holds the condition is a permanent sequence such as $1,1,1,1,1,$ which also converges (to $1$) so I think it is true but not sure how to put it formally.

Noam

Comment: it's false.  Let $a_n=\sum_{k=1}^n \frac 1k$.

Comment: The fact that the claim is false is basically the reason behind half the questions about sequences and series.

Comment: This is saying that any series whose terms tend to zero converges. False!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take $a_n=\sqrt {n} $.

$$a_{n+1}-a_n=$$
$$\frac{(\sqrt{n+1}-\sqrt{n})(\sqrt {n+1}+\sqrt {n})}{\sqrt {n+1}+\sqrt {n}} $$

$$=\frac {1}{\sqrt {n+1}+\sqrt {n}} $$

$$\implies \lim_{\infty}(a_{n+1}-a_n)=0$$
but
$$\lim_{\infty}a_n=+\infty $$

Comment: Thank you for the edit. I figured it out so I deleted the comment but thanks anyway

Comment: @Noam No problem friend of the world.